# Possible to redact information in the clipboard, or to auto-redact when it hits a webpage?

Tags: web-browser, data-leakage, client-side, social-engineering, clipboard

Sometimes when I paste information [to a website](http://stackexchange.com/) I realize after I post the information that I inadvertently included an IP address, username, email address, or other information I'd like to consider private.

Is there a clipboard filter (or keyboard combination) that will filter the text prior to me posting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some success finding sample tools by doing a search for "[clipboard regex](http://www.google.com/search?q=clipboard%20regex)". AutoHotKey is a Windows system utility and Firefox has a filtered clipboard plugin available as well.

Additionally, it seems that operating systems tend to make clipboard monitoring a fairly simple task to program, so you could write whatever filters you'd like yourself with relatively minor pain as programming projects go.